# Find the difference of values between 2 columns after joining 2 tables on ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in MS SQL Server 2019 - test1 and test2. Below are the table creation and insert statements for the 2 tables :

```
create table test2 (id nvarchar(10) , code nvarchar(5) , all_names nvarchar(80))
create table test3 (code nvarchar(5), name1 nvarchar(18) )

insert into test2 values ('A01', '50493', '12A2S0403-Buffalo;13A1T0101-Boston;13A2C0304-Miami')
insert into test2 values ('A02', '31278', '12A1S0205-Detroit')
insert into test2 values ('A03', '49218', '12A2S0403-Buffalo;12A1M0208-Manhattan')

insert into test3 values ('50493', 'T0101-Boston')
insert into test3 values ('49218', 'S0403-Buffalo')
insert into test3 values ('31278', 'S0205-Detroit')
```

I can join the 2 tables on the code column. Task is to find difference of test2.all_names and test3.name1. For example 'A01' should display the result as '12A2S0403-Buffalo;13A2C0304-Miami'.
A02 should not come as output.

The output should be :

```
Id  |   Diff_of_name
----------------------------------------
A01 |   12A2S0403-Buffalo;13A2C0304-Miami
A03 |   12A1M0208-Manhattan
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution, first using *openjson* to split your source string into rows, then using *exists* to check for matching values in table `test3` and finally *string_agg* to provide the final result:

```
select Id, String_Agg(j.[value], ';') within group (order by j.seq) Diff_Of_Name
from test2 t2
cross apply (
  select j.[value],  Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) Seq
  from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(all_names,';', '","'),'"]')) j
  where not exists (
    select * from test3 t3 
    where t3.code = t2.code and j.[value] like Concat('%',t3.name1,'%')
  )
)j
group by t2.Id;
```

Demo [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cbc392620f11b326f81e3f5a170cdb1f)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the need to normalize.  However, if one must normalize,  STRING_SPLIT is handy.
When done with the real work, STRING_AGG can de-normalize the data.

```
WITH normalized as ( -- normalize all_names in test2 to column name1
    SELECT t2.id, t2.code, t2.all_names, n.value as [name1]
    FROM test2 t2 
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.all_names, ';') n
) select * from normalized;

WITH normalized as ( -- normalize all_names in test2 to column name1
    SELECT t2.id, t2.code, t2.all_names, n.value as [name1]
    FROM test2 t2 
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t2.all_names, ';') n
), differenced as ( -- exclude name1 values listed in test3, ignoring leading characters
    SELECT n.* 
    FROM normalized n
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test3 t3 WHERE t3.code = n.code AND n.name1 LIKE '%' + t3.name1)
) -- denormalize
SELECT id, STRING_AGG(name1, ';') as [Diff_of_name] 
FROM differenced
group by id
order by id
```

```
id         Diff_of_name
---------- ---------------------------------
A01        12A2S0403-Buffalo;13A2C0304-Miami
A03        12A1M0208-Manhattan
```

Comment: `String_Split` does not guarantee ordering - from the documentation, *The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string* - this may or may not be important to the OP.